# Locally hosted GPL/BSD Time tracking application for multiple users

Tags: gratis, project-management, time-management

My company is looking for an upgrade to our time tracking application in the form of throwing out the old one.

Currently we have (and would require for the new application):

- Multiple users
- Writes to database (as opposed to flat file)
- Can be hosted on a machine within our own network
- Free (it's homegrown, in future ones we'd like GPL/BSD licensing if possible) or low-cost ( < 10 users)
- The system isn't for tracking how much a person worked, but for how much time was put into working on certain customer's project(s)

Things we would like in a new one:

- Arbitrary sub-categorizing (see bottom of post)
- Ability to add new customers from the web interface (In our current system we manually add it to the DB with an SQL Insert)
- Preferably written in PHP, python or java if it's open source, but this isn't a hard requirement
- Built in analytics (just numbers is fine, no need for anything fancy)

---

For arbitrary sub-categorizing, we currently have a system that looks like:

```
Customer
    Project 1
    Project 2
    Support
```

And can go no "deeper" in levels of indentation

What we would like is to be able to do

```
Customer
     Support
         Email support
         On-site support
     System change requests
         #1
         #2
```

Comment: Can I suggest that you are looking for a time tracking system rather than a timesheet system?

Comment: Looking into it, I think you're right, we just call ours a timesheet